# C - Reading unknown formatted input

Tags: c, parsing, input, format

I have a text file as input that has an unknown number of lines and a semi-unknown format. An example would be:

```
p1 a x1 300
p2 b x3 200 c x2 x1 500
p3 c x1 x3 1500 b x2 100 a x3 800
```

Where the *'c'* operations involve two *'x'* objects and the others involve one. The order of the operations can be random, and the amount of operations is also random. I need to store the *'p'* number, operation type, associated *'x'* object(s) and the integer at the end of the operation.

I don't know how to go about storing this data as `scanf()` only works with formatted input that is known. I've tried to traverse each line character-by-character using `getc()` but I can't detect the end of a file this way while also trying to grab and check multiple characters.

If anyone could help me figure out a way to store this data I would appreciate it.

---

**EDIT:**

My text file has other lines, too, but the final portion is the one I've specified. Currently this only grabs the first operation in the line 'n' times, where 'n' is the total number of operations in the line.

```
    for (i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
    if(fgets(line, MAXCHAR, fp)) {
        if (line[0] == 'p' && isdigit(line[1])) { // Check if we are interested in parsing the line
            k = opCount(line); // Amount of operations in line - Working
            data[c_count].t_num = k;
            data[c_count].trans = calloc(data[c_count].t_num, sizeof(clients));
            for (j = 0; j < k; j++) {
                tempBuf = strdup(line);
                if(tempBuf) {
                    token = strtok(tempBuf, delim);
                    if(token) {
                        //1st of n sections = p1 a x1 300
                        token = strtok(NULL, " ");//parsing on space now
                        if(token) {
                            strcpy(data[c_count].trans[j].lineNum, token);
                            //2nd section is opType
                            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
                            if (token) {
                                data[c_count].trans[j].op_type = atoi(token);
                                token = strtok(NULL, " ");
                                if (token) {
                                    data[c_count].trans[j].val = atoi(token);
                                }
                            }
                        }                        
                    }
                }
                free(tempBuf);
            }
            c_count++;
        }
    }
```

I'm also not sure this accounts for the 'c' case, where two objects are involved...

Comment: Read whole lines into a buffer, and then parse the line in the buffer. If the maximum possible size of the lines are known and not overly large, then you can use plain arrays and [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets).

Comment: "only works with formatted input that is known". You do know the format of the input. It's not the same on each line but it's a known format. So read/parse each "token" and depending on the value of that token you then know how to interpret the next token.

Comment: I think you need to add more information. For instance: What is the data structure where data shall be stored? The code you have tried so far.

Comment: You really should try to include a [mcve], but even so, your question has merit.  The syntax of your example input text is known well enough... `Where the 'c' operations involve two 'x' objects and the others involve one. The order of the operations can be random, and the amount of operations is also random. I need to store the 'p' number, operation type, associated 'x' object(s) and the integer at the end of the operation.`   ...that it should be able to be parsed into an array of `struct`.  See answer below for a suggested approach.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'd like to use `fgets`, however when I read a whole line into a buffer using this, I can't iterate over the line without getting a segmentation fault/weird characters.

Comment: That could with a little work be a good question on its own.

Answer (score 1):

*...don't know how to go about storing this data as scanf()...*.

From what you have described in your post, the syntax of your input is actually known well enough to parse it.  Here are some suggestions, and some pseudo code to get you started:

Note:  *[scanf](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_scanf.htm)* is not the best choice for parsing strings, even if there is some predictability to their syntax.  I suggest learning to use *[fgets](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm)* in conjunction with *[strtok](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm)* (or strtok_r) as an alternative.

```
const char filespec[] = {"C:\\dev\\play\\data.txt"};

typedef struct { //container for operation/line
    char lineNum[10];
    char opType;
    char op[2];
    int val; //you did not describe this in question
}OP;


typedef struct { //container for each line
     int opsCountOnLine;
     OP *section;
 }LINE;

const char *subs[] = {" a ", " b ", " c "};


int getLineCount(const char *filespec);//Counts '\n'.  Adjust function if other criteria
int countOfOpsPerLine(const char line);//Counts occurances of 'a', 'b', 'c', ... on a line

     int main(void)
     {
        int lineCount = getLineCount(filespec);
        int i;
        char line[280]; //adjust as necessary
        FILE *fp = NULL;

        LINE *lines = calloc(lineCount, sizeof(*lines));
        if(lines)
        {
            fp = fopen(filespec, "r");
            if(fp)
            {
                for(i=0;i<lineCount;i++)
                {
                    if(fgets(line, 280, fp))
                    {
                       //here is where LINE can be populated with content of each line
                       //1. determine operations in 'line'.  
                       lines[i].opsCountOnLine = countOfOpsPerLine(line);
                       //2. allocate memory for sections.  
                       lines[i].section = calloc(lines[i].opsCountOnLine, sizeof(OP));
                       for(j=0;j<lines[i].opsCountOnLine;j++)
                       {

                           tempBuf = strdup(line);
                           if(tempBuf)
                           {
                               //SEE EDIT below for suggested content in this inner loop.                           
                               //3. Parse line into lines[i].section[0].line, lines[i].section[0].opType, etc.  
                               //   using delimiter of "abc" (...def...) with strtok()
                               //4. Other steps???
                               //then free tempBuf so you can use it again in the loop
                               free(tempBuf);  
                        }

                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        //notify user of error, exit
                        free(lines);
                    }
                }
                fclose(fp);
            }
        }  
         return 0;
     }

    int countOfOpsPerLine(const char *line) //Counts occurances of 'a', 'b', 'c', ... on a line 
    {
        int count=0, i;
        char *tok;
        // Parse line to find number of sections
        for(i=0;i<sizeof(subs)/sizeof(subs[0]);i++)
        {
            tok = strstr(line,subs[i]);
            if(tok != NULL) count++;
        }

        return count;   
    }

int getLineCount(const char *filespec)
{
    int c=0, count=0;
    FILE *fp = fopen(filespec, "r");
    if(fp)
    {
        for (c = getc(fp); c != EOF; c = getc(fp))
        {
            if (c == '\n') // Increment count if this character is newline 
            {
                count = count + 1;
            }
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
    return count;
}
```

*EDIT* to include suggestion for inner loop  (and edited main struct above)
Since your input text seems to use a or b or c for opType, you  can use them as the delimiteror...
you can use

```
const char delim[] = {"abc"};

char *tok;

tok = strtok(tempBuf, delim);
if(tok)
{
    //1st of n sections = p1 a x1 300
    tok = strtok(NULL, " ");//parsing on space now
    {
        if(tok)
        {
            strcpy(lines[i].section[j].lineNum, tok);
            //2nd section is opType
            tok = strtok(NULL)
            if(tok)
            {
                lines[i].section[j].opType = atoi(tok);
                //3rd section is op (and so on...)
                //repeat the same process here until you 
                //parsed and placed all members 
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I already had the line count; and I follow until I have to parse the line into sections. With `strtok()` it would just return the first part of the line (_p1, etc._) correct? How would I parse the rest of the line to find opType, etc.?

Comment: @Alex - There will be two levels of parsing per line, once you know the number of operations in the line, for example in this line: p3 c x1 x3 1500 b x2 100 a x3 800, you know there are 3 operations: c x1 x3 1500, b x2 100 and a x3 800, you would parse the main line into these, then you would parse these sub-strings into opType, op and val. So, you are going to have at lease two loops, the main loop uses the i index in my example, then an inside loop, indexed perhaps with j to pars and assign the values to the struct. Added some more detail to the inner loop...

Comment: @Alex - See edits for how a way to parse in the lnner loop area.

Comment: I'm using your code suggestions but I fear I'm still not getting the results I'm looking for. See my edit

Comment: @Alex - The fundamentals of how to do everything you have described has been provided, with illustration. If there are modifications to fine tune to your needs, then make them. Use conditional statements such as if-else if needed to surround special conditions, such as the two operations in c type operations: `if(opType==c){parse 2 operations}else{parse 1 operation}`. Make adjustments to the member types in the struct as needed to accommodate what you want to store. (strings or integer values). Beyond that, good luck. I hope I have helped.